# Regex expression validation form for two different URLS

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am creating a validation form that can only accept two types of urls. 
These URLs need to be either a rent or sale url. The examples I have are:

> http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-38983423.html
>   http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-to-rent/property-39474762.html

I currently have a RegEx expression for finding just the sale url which is:

```
/http:\/\/(www\.)(rightmove\.)(co\.)(uk\/)(property-for-sale\/)(property-)[0-9]{8}(\.html)/g
```

I am having trouble however trying to write a RegEx expression for finding either a sale or rent url. I am new to RegEx so this is difficult for me. I know I have to use the | operator but I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
property-for-sale\/
```

With

```
property-(?:for-sale|to-rent)\/
```